# Как правильно использовать Fork/Join Framework в Java?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Я пишу простую програму с использованием Fork/Join Framework. Для первой версии моей програмы я использовал, в качестве примера, код из книги Гербера Шилда "Java 7. Руководство для начинающих", для второй - код из Гугла. Почему версия из книги не работает должным образом (не все участки фрагментируются), ведь разница в коде только лишь в запуске дополнительного потока?

V1:

```
if (to - from < range) {
  for (int i = from; i < to; i++) {
    int result = checker.checkCode(i);
    if (result != CodeChecker.INCORRECT_CODE) {
      stop.set(true);
      return result;
    }
  }
  return CodeChecker.INCORRECT_CODE;
 } else {
   int            middle = (int) (((long) from + to) >> 1);
   BruteForceTask left;
   BruteForceTask right;
   left = new BruteForceTask(uri, from, middle, range, checker);
   right = new BruteForceTask(uri, middle, to, range, checker);
   left.fork();
   right.fork();
   int leftResult = left.join();
   int rightResult = right.join();
   return leftResult != CodeChecker.INCORRECT_CODE ? leftResult : rightResult;
 }
```

V2:

```
else {
   int            middle = (int) (((long) from + to) >> 1);
   BruteForceTask left;
   BruteForceTask right;
   left = new BruteForceTask(uri, from, middle, range, checker);
   right = new BruteForceTask(uri, middle, to, range, checker);
   left.fork();
   int rightResult = right.invoke();
   int leftResult = left.join();
   return leftResult != CodeChecker.INCORRECT_CODE ? leftResult : rightResult;
 }
```

Main:

```
ForkJoinPool   pool       = new ForkJoinPool();
BruteForceTask bruteForce = null;
bruteForce = new BruteForceTask(uri, from, to, range, codeChecker);
result = pool.invoke(bruteForce);
```

Comment: Киньте остальные классы - не у всех на столе или в компе есть исходники

Comment: @dSH не совсем вас понял: зачем?? Функция класса WebCodeChecker::checkCode() не имеет отношения к многопоточности (там просто оправляется и проверяется запрос). В BruteForceTask нет ничего кроме конструкторов, а функция compute() полностью приведена.

Comment: Все таки приведите. Потому что есть вопросы точно ли ошибка в приведенных участках кода.

Comment: "WebCodeChecker::checkCode() не имеет отношения к многопоточности (там просто оправляется и проверяется запрос)" - может его код приведете - а то он у вас в несколько потоков вызывается ?- в нем точно нет разделяемых данных? и как проверяете что "не все участки фрагментируются"?

Comment: @dSH Спасибо за ответы.
Не знаю, проблема ли это, или так должно быть (имхо - проблема),
но потоки дальше фрагментировались, просто после длительного ожидания (когда некоторые другие завершились). Вот тут весь проект: https://mega.nz/#F!xlRHjJya!OHBxxKEnZjYxQYuG5pijRg. Буду признателен, если укажите на ошибку.